# onclick works on this radio button restyle, but onmousedown doesn't

Tags: css

I have a set of radio buttons, and everything works fine when onclick is used, but when onclick is replaced with onmousedown (or ontouchstart, tested in developer mode), checked+label works fine, but the alert requested in the HTML doesn't. The reason why I want to replace onclick (with ontouchstart) is to improve the performance of a hybrid app in IOS.
Any clue what my problem is... I've managed to get from zero coding to creating a quite complex physics app in 5 months without posting a single question anywhere, and I quite embarrassed by this one!
Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="switch-field1">
                        <input type="radio" id="sine1" name="switch_3"  onclick = "alert('This works fine')" checked/>
                        <label for="sine1"> SINE  </label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="square1" name="switch_3"  onmousedown = "alert('If I see this, problem solved')"/>
                        <label for="square1"> SQUARE </label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="triangle1" name="switch_3"  onclick = "alert('This works fine')"/>
                        <label for="triangle1"> TRIANGLE </label>
                  </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.switch-field1 {
    font-family: "sans-serif", Tahoma, Verdana, Lucida ;
      padding: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;}
    .switch-title1 {
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-left: 0px}
    .switch-field1 input {
        position: absolute !important;
        clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        border: 0;
        overflow: hidden}
    .switch-field1 label {
      float: left;}
    .switch-field1 label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #e6ffe6;
      color: black;
      font-size:11px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);}
    .switch-field1 input:checked + label {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: white;
      background-color: #009900;}
```

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

The `onmousedown` event works, but only on the radio button, not on the label.

You should attach an event listener to the label itself, like:

`<label for="square1" onmousedown="alert('If I see this, problem solved')">SQUARE</label>`

Update:

The `ontouchstart` with function call worked for me, but you need to use it on touch capable 'device', I used the chrome device toolbar under dev tools (ctrl+shift+j, mobile icon at top left).

I used this function:

```
function whichbuttonID(){

  // need js to select the option
  document.getElementById("squarel").checked = true;
  alert('Ok');
}
```

Comment: Hi Tamas...Thank you for taking the time to answer, and it works great, alert appears on the first touch of the button!... I am so very grateful. But...(there's always a but...), when I replace the alert with a  call to a function  <input type="radio" id="square1" name="switch_3">
                        <label for="square1" ontouchstart="whichbuttonID()"> SQUARE </label>  the ontouchstart doesn't work the first time it's touched, but works the second time, without exception. Any idea why this might be so. I've searched for an answer, with no luck.